# What are all the types of scientific articles?

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission

While doing some research I found some context where scientist A publishes a research article about newly generated progress they made in a field. Another researcher B, skeptical of this paper, publishes a "Review paper", and analyses what A has written. To which then A responds by writing an article titled as "Research commentary" to retort on the latter.

Throughout this development is where I had the question hit me, how many kinds of scientific articles are there? I am personally still on my first year of PhD research, so I have not yet published a paper or had to confront a journal, but I was still surprised to not see an exhaustive answer to this question here or anywhere else, to which I believe would be really beneficial to sorting and understanding articles and giving more context to state of the art research in any specific field.

Comment: Do some research and publish it - maybe it could be the seminal paper of the decade...

Comment: I don't think such exhaustive categorisation would be terribly helpful.
Note that the names given to "types" of paper are not defined worldwide, but depend on the journal or publisher.

Comment: Different fields (and even subfields) have different conventions; it may be helpful to specify which field you are interested in.

Comment: Requests for lists are "shopping questions" and off-topic.  In this case the list would be quite long.

Comment: And to add: I think you are misunderstanding what a `review paper` is supposed to be. A review is not there to rebut a specific paper your are skeptical of, but to summarize (or review) a specific topic based on published literature.

Answer (score 4):

There is probably no exhaustive taxonomy. The options depend on the database. Databases of scientific publications usually contain the variable 'document type' (or so) in their metadata, and have a wide range of options for operationalising that type.

For example, *Web of Science* lists their document types [here](https://images.webofknowledge.com/WOKRS59B4/help/WOS/hs_document_type.html#:%7E:text=Some%20records%20in%20Web%20of,a%20book%20of%20confernece%20proceedings.). They include, inter alia, 'Article', 'Biographical Item', 'Correction', 'Database Review', 'Excerpt', 'Hardware Review', 'Music Score', 'Reprint', and 'Retraction'.

*Scopus* has a smaller list; you can see its document types [in this PDF](https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/pdf_file/0007/69451/Scopus_ContentCoverage_Guide_WEB.pdf) on pp. 11-12.

*ORCID* likewise allows you to choose from many options regarding the 'work types'; [see the list here](https://members.orcid.org/api/resources/work-types). They include, to name some examples, 'book-chapter', 'dictionary-entry', 'dissertation', 'encyclopedia-entry', 'edited-book', 'journal-issue', 'manual', 'newsletter-article', 'supervised-student-pulication', 'translation' and 'working-papers'.